# Browse Files and folders uploaded on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm writing from Italy (sorry for mistakes), my question is about GOOGLE DRIVE API and
I'm writing here because the G-Suite support wrote me to contact you, I'm not a programmer.

The big question is: how can I browse folders and files uploaded on my Google Drive Api?

I write you what apppened.

I wanted to use a backup program to save in a planned way files and folders an Google Drive.
I downloaded the program (Iperius Backup) and followed the instructions.
To understand on what I did, I paste the link of the instructions below:

http://www.iperiusbackup.net/en/backup-to-google-drive/

http://www.iperiusbackup.net/en/how-to-enable-google-drive-api-and-get-client-credentials/

I tried the software and everything worked.

So I opened Google Drive but the back-upped files weren't there.

Seen that there was something not clear, I have erased all the files on my Google Drive. I wanted  to make sure that it was empty, hoping to erase also “hidden files”(...even if I thought it wouldn't have been so simple...)

To make sure that everything was erased (also  “hidden files”), I tried to restore files from the backup software but unfortunately, the software worked well...the files were still there, somewhere...

This means that I have saved through the backup software files and folders on Google Drive “Api”, but I cannot manage them.

How can I have access to my space in Google Drive Api and erase all my files and folders that are still there?

Thank you in advance for the help,

best regards,

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

To list all files in your drive, you can use [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

> This method accepts the `q` parameter, which is a search query
>   combining one or more search terms. For more information, see the
>   [Search for Files and Team Drives guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters).

You can use the [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it) or use the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#examples) given in a specific language you are using.

To delete/erase a file, use [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete).

> Permanently deletes a file by ID. Skips the trash. The currently
>   authenticated user must own the file or be an organizer on the parent
>   for Team Drive files. [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete#try-it) or [see an example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete#examples).